# Ubuntu won't install on Windows 8 HD

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8

So basically I installed Windows 8 and have not found it a decent OS, to my chagrin when I tried to install the latest Ubuntu via flash, the flash drive wouldn't load. It just went to the windows 8 startup page. I changed the boot settings and everything, any thoughts?

**NOTE: Flash drive created from uncompressing the iso onto my flash drive via 7zip.**

Comment: How was the flash created?

Comment: The thoughts are that "didn't work" is not nearly enough information to give any advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Uncompressed ISO onto a disk doesn't make it bootable.

Please have a read http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

There are some other programs also to create bootable USB disk for ubuntu.

- [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
- [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you enabled booting from USB, but the hard drive is still listed as the first boot device. That means it will ignore the USB because it found the bootable hard drive when it checked the boot devices in the order listed. You need to press F12 (or sometimes Escape) during the boot process to select the USB as the boot device. Sometimes a system will ignore F12 unless it is pressed at just the right stage of the boot process. If the happens, try several times, pressing F12 a little sooner each time.

Answer (score 0):

I recently purchased a new laptop and I had the same problem. I was trying to boot Backtrack 5 from my USB drive. The way I got it to work was I went to the BIOS and went under the "Boot Override" settings and chose my USB drive as a boot device. From there, Backtrack 5 Linux booted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new laptop with Windows 8 on it then the BIOS is probably a UEFI type.  You may have to set it back to legacy.

Also, Use pendrivelinux to create the USB flash drive.  Make sure that you run pendrivelinux as administrator under windows so that you have rights to write the boot record.